# TextBox for product code - handling the dashes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `TextBox` where a user is meant to enter a product code that looks like this:

`XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX`

What I'm trying to do is automatically placing the dashes in the right place as the user is typing, so that they only have to enter the actual code itself (similar to what's done in various pieces of software).

The problems I'm encountering have got to do with the position of the cursor as the user is typing.

My current solution (partially working) is as the following:

```
private void textBoxProductKey_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) || textBoxProductKey.Text.Length == 29)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }

    var cursorPosition = textBoxProductKey.SelectionStart;
    string text;

    if (cursorPosition == 0)
    {
        text = e.KeyChar + textBoxProductKey.Text;
    }
    else if (cursorPosition == textBoxProductKey.Text.Length)
    {
        text = textBoxProductKey.Text + e.KeyChar;
    }
    else
    {
        text = textBoxProductKey.Text.Insert(cursorPosition, e.KeyChar.ToString());
    }

    text = Regex.Replace(text, "-", "");
    text = Regex.Replace(text, ".{5}", "$0-");
    textBoxProductKey.Text = text.Length <= 29 ? text : text.Substring(0, 29);

    textBoxProductKey.SelectionStart = cursorPosition / 6 == (cursorPosition + 1) / 6
        ? cursorPosition + 1
        : cursorPosition + 2;

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The two problems with my current solution are

- It doesn't properly handle the delete/backspace keys where potentially the dashes need to be deleted/inserted in different locations and the cursor position re-calculated
- It doesn't work properly if the `cursorPosition == textBoxProductKey.Text.Length`.

The latter is very easy to fix, but I'm struggling with the former and also feel like the code is a bit convoluted.

How can I more easily achieve this (note the plan is to continue using a `TextBox` object).

**EDIT**

I am aware of the `MaskedTextBox` control, I do not want to use a `MaskedTextBox`, I want to use a `TextBox`.

What I am trying to do is not outside the realms of possibility for a `TextBox`, even if there are "easier" ways to accomplish this with other controls.

Also I feel like this is a great question for teaching people how to work with the cursor in a `TextBox` (among other things probably).

Comment: The `MaskedTextBox` might be what you are looking for ► [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) - In regards to `note the plan is to continue using a TextBox object` - All I can say is, use the right tool for the right job, otherwise your custom code might end up trying to fix specific issues for specific scenarios continuously,..hammer, square peg, round hole,etc..

Comment: `I am aware of the MaskedTextBox control, I do not want to use a MaskedTextBox, I want to use a TextBox.` - Of course its possible and there is plenty of SO posts out there already showing you how to implement your own masking code on a Textbox but they all suffer from problems, hence,..use MaskedtextBox. `Also I feel like this is a great question for teaching people how to work with the cursor in a TextBox` - I'm not sure if doing that by teaching how not to use the right tool for the right job and over-complicating a simple solution is the right way to go about IMHO.

Comment: Did you try saving your previous text value? That way you can compare by length and value after every change - useful if the user is pasting text, too.

Comment: @Fran, the right tool for the job is what you make it. To say that a control that is basically a `TextBox` but with added verification is better than a more stripped down version of it is like saying no one should ever use `Sockets` because there's a `TcpClient`.

Comment: @cogumel0 - If you want to re-invent the wheel, you can look at the `MaskedTextBox` source code and replicate what you need ► [http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/MaskedTextBox@cs/3/MaskedTextBox@cs](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/MaskedTextBox@cs/3/MaskedTextBox@cs)

Comment: @Fran, what part about my question is not clear enough? You keep coming back with the `MaskedTextBox` despite me having already said 4x (including this one) that I will use a `TextBox`. If I wanted a `MaskedTextBox`, I would use one. To look at the code of the `MaskedTextBox` and replicate it would leave me with a `MaskedTextBox`, which I unfortunately find myself saying way too often I do not want. Can you please stay on topic?

Comment: @OriNachum and how would I detect whether the backspace/delete key was pressed?

Comment: @cogumel0 - If you replicate parts of the logic the `MaskedTextBox` source code is using to handle a mask your are not using the `MaskedTextBox`. You might find your answer in that source code but off course still would be using your TextBox.

Comment: @Fran, sorry didn't realize the point of SO was so people could point others at 3000~ lines of code and say "your answer might be in there somewhere". My bad...

Comment: @cogumel0 - Dude, I spent 1h trying to find resources to help you and all you do is reply with the highest degree of sarcasm and arrogance. Good Luck :)

Comment: @Fran, I'm confident I'm already on the right path, took the time to post my code and ask for a way to handle the backspace/delete and potentially improve how I'm doing the rest (which is working, with the exception of the small "bug" mentioned, though it can be fixed in one line). In every single one of your comments you keep pushing me towards something I don't want to use and since the start you're basically telling me I'm doing it wrong. I'd much prefer help with getting it to work with what I already have or if you the path I've chosen is a bad idea, that you suggest another alternative.

Comment: By the path I've chosen I don't mean my choice of a `TextBox` as the control to use by the way, I mean the code I'm currently using and the approach with the `KeyPress`.

Comment: @cogumel0, does backspace/delete/ctrl+v not work on OnKeyPressed? (By the way, should also test "insert" cases)

Comment: @OriNachum they work, but how do know exactly which key was pressed from `KeyPressEventArgs` ?

Comment: @cogumel0, basically this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs(v=vs.110).aspx Also, there are some keys you can't get according to here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar(v=vs.110).aspx But what I suggest is: don't try and react to the key pressed - only parse again the whole text.

Comment: @OriNachum my point is that document clearly states you can't get or set a Delete for example, which is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the MaskedTextBox control? It might be more appropriate.

The MaskedTextBox is designed precisely for this type of requirement and would answer your original question.

You may find it more difficult to implement this functionality yourself with a normal TextBox. It's also worth weighing up which solution is more likely to be be bug-free and easier to maintain.

It may helpful if you could to explain to us why you would prefer use a TextBox over a MaskedTextBox.

Comment: I have, and decided against it (as mentioned in my question the plan is to continue using a `TextBox` object). Also I don't this would be the sort of thing you'd put in a *comment*, not an answer, as it does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Despite your edits, this is still not an answer, and has been discussed to death in the comments section (where this belongs) that I am not willing to use a `MaskedTextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing our conversation, save your current caret position, parse the whole text as if it's new, and return the caret to its original position.

That way you handle deleting as well as copy-pasting

Comment: Returning the caret to original position is not always the desired effect. Imagine this scenario: user is typing the product key and he's gotten to 5 characters, so he types `12345` for example. At this point the length of the string is 5, and the caret sits at pos 5. Now because a dash should be automatically added every 5 chars, a dash is now added, so the string is `12345-` and, according to what you said, the caret placed back in its original position. Now the caret will be just before the dash, when it should be after it.

Comment: You suggest something like `TextChanged`, not `KeyPress`. But that won't work, you need to know whether the delete or backspace key was pressed. Scenario: user has `12345-6` on the with the caret sitting between the 5 and the hyphen. If they press delete, the text should be `12345` with the caret sitting after the 5 (caret does not move). However, if the caret is sitting between the hyphen and the 6 and they press backspace, the text should be `12346` with the caret sitting between the 4 and the 6 (caret moves back one position). Knowing whether delete or backspace was pressed is crucial!